# What do the arguments "name__icontains" and "description__icontains" mean in a Django query filter?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```
maps = (maps.filter(name__icontains=search_terms) |
            maps.filter(description__icontains=search_terms))
```

I can't find the meaning of these filter arguments.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#icontains

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a [case-insensitive containment test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#icontains).

Example:

```
Entry.objects.get(headline__icontains='Lennon')
```

SQL equivalent:

```
SELECT ... WHERE headline ILIKE '%Lennon%';
```

---

In your case the code says maps should be `True` if either the name or the description field contains the value of `search_terms`.

Answer (score 3):

`xxx_icontains` searches the whole `xxx` field for the argument, case-insensitively.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#icontains